# How to set 'image tag mutability' using CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-ecr

When one would like to create an Elastic Container Registry then it is possible to set 'image tag mutability':

> Image tag mutability
>
> The image tag mutability setting for the
> repository. Select "immutable" to prevent image tags from being
> overwritten by subsequent image pushes using the same tag. Mutable
> Immutable

According to [this user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecr-repository.html) it does not seem to be possible to configure this using AWS CloudFormation.

Comment: As Dan1701 said unfortunately it takes some time for features to make it into CloudFormation. Not that this is a suitable answer, but just in case you have the ability to use a different tool... have a look at Terraform (which does support ECR immutable image tags) or Pulumi (which probably does, but I don't use it so am not sure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ImageTagMutability` property in ECR is not currently supported in CloudFormation, as verified by experimentation (nor is it part of the LifecyclePolicy property). There is sometimes lag between feature availability in CloudFormation, and the mutability flag [was only introduced in late July](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/amazon-ecr-now-supports-immutable-image-tags/).

This comes up elsewhere in the corners of AWS, including:

- AWS Global Accelerator - this entire service is not provisionable using CloudFormation.
- AWS WAF geo match rules cannot be created in CFN.